# modifying printindex to eliminate toc entry

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing

I want to modify \printindex to eliminate the  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index
line so that an entry does not appear in the table of contents

Comment: What's the reason for not having the Index in the Table of Contents?

Comment: your second version of the question is much better, thanks for providing a MWE :) for future, please just edit your original question :)